# Noticed this request in access.log, any explanation on what the attempt was supposed to achieve?

Tags: apache, security, web

`46.19.***.*** - - [22/Sep/2014:12:18:27 +0300] "\x1e\x19\xcd\x9d]\xd9\xf3g4\xb3\x04\x88\xa6z\xbc\xf0[\x9e\xe2}0\x9d\xe4>h\xee" 403 - "-" "-"`

I'm running the server on my local machine as a developing environment, I don't know how they managed to find my IP but I'm curious to know what they were trying to do.

**Edit:** Decoding it returns `Í�]Ùóg4³�¦z¼ð[�â}0�ä>hî` which is... gibberish.